# Hyperledger Fabric Adding Org - cryptogen does not parse configtx.yaml correctly

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to add a new organization to the Fabric test-network (v2.2).
I've created a configtx.yaml file that is on the add-org-org5/docker folder (source: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/d55916b4b7151027ee3349b867e9fbdc):

```
Organizations:
  - &org5
    Name:  org5MSP
    ID: org5MSP
    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org5MSP.example.com/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org5MSP.admin','org5MSP.peer','org5MSP.client')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule:
          - "OR('org5MSP.admin','org5MSP.client')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule:
          - "OR('org5MSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule:
          - "OR('org5MSP.peer')"
```

When running `configtxgen -printOrg org5MSP -configPath /add-org-org5/docker`, I obtain the following (full log: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/8144665eda4f91229f32d1b1f42058f2):

```
'\x1B[35m2021-05-21 16:05:03.341 UTC [common.tools.configtxgen] func1 -> PANI 012\x1B[0m failed to load configCache: Error unmarshaling config into struct: 3 error(s) decoding:\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
    "* 'Organizations[0].Policies[Admins].Rule' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'\r\n" +
    "* 'Organizations[0].Policies[Endorsement].Rule' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'\r\n" +
    "* 'Organizations[0].Policies[Writers].Rule' expected type 'string', got unconvertible type '[]interface {}'\r\n" +
    'panic: failed to load configCache: Error unmarshaling config into struct: 3 error(s) decoding:\r\n' +
    '\r\n' +
```

It looks like cryptogen is not recognizing the "Rule" strings. Why is that? Any advice?

Everything works well with the default configtx.yaml file (source: https://gist.github.com/RafaelAPB/a1d9269d94f8f4f4d87b60d54c7b2247):

```
Organizations:
    - &Org3
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org3MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org3MSP

        MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.peer', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin', 'Org3MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org3MSP.peer')"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shuould modify your org5 configtx.yaml to these,you can find field `Rule`
are different.

```
Organizations:
  - &org5
    Name:  org5MSP
    ID: org5MSP
    MSPDir: ../organizations/peerOrganizations/org5MSP.example.com/msp
    Policies:
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org5MSP.admin','org5MSP.peer','org5MSP.client')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org5MSP.admin','org5MSP.client')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org5MSP.admin')"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('org5MSP.peer')"
```